# Setting X-UA-Compatible in http header doesn't change document.documentMode for html in browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an application that supports IE9 (IE10 compatibility mode) and am trying view another application (supports IE10 only) in an IFrame. For the specific pages of the parent application making a call to the pages of the child application I want to render the parent and child pages in "IE=edge" or "IE=10" so that the functionality of the child application works.

I wrote a servlet filter to interpret the request and set the value of User-Agent and X-UA-Compatible. However, the value of document.documentMode still shows as "8" i.e. IE 8 in javascript when the page is rendered. I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly. Pasted the code snippet below and any help is appreciated:-

```
public class DocumentsFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain    filterChain) 
                throws IOException, ServletException {

         HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
         resp.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10");

         String ua = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getHeader("User-Agent");
         ua = ua.replaceAll("MSIE 7.0", "MSIE 10.0");
         resp.setHeader("User-Agent", ua);

         filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

   }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not fix your websites to support all modern browsers?

Comment: Since we use a proprietary application that would involve a full upgrade of the application which is a significant effort.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that you are setting the doctype? Old versions of IE automatically revert to quirks mode without it.
http://webdesign.about.com/cs/doctype/a/aaquirksmode.htm

Comment: So the page that gets rendered actually gets rendered from proprietary technology so I don't have control over the actual HTML page contents. However when I did a "View Source" I saw the following:-

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html dir="LTR">    As per the link you pasted this looks like "Almost Standards mode". Could that be why it is rendering as IE 8?

    <head>

Comment: So after removing the filter that I added the document.documentMode value prints as "5" always. So my filter is making it go till "8" i.e. IE 8 but not till IE 10 which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the article it sounds like the  is an important element for the browser to decide how to render the page. Even though the X-UA-Compatible flag is set, unless the DocType is set to the appropriate value, the page will render as though it is in older versions of the browser. Please let me know if this assumption is not correct.